# why can't I connect to the database using wildfly data?

Tags: database, postgresql, deployment, jboss, wildfly

This is the first time I try to deploy my application using wildfly to a remote server, it seems that I succeeded, but now I cannot connect the created database. wildfly says that

`Connection URL = jdbc:postgresql:/var/run/postgresql:5432`,

I use this string to connect

`<property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql:/var/run/postgresql:5432?currentSchema=myshema&amp;user=user&amp;password=pass</property>`

For this I get

`Connection error: : org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "/var/run/postgresql:5432" does not exist`

in logs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're trying to connect to a **unix socket** (/var/run/postgesql), it can't be on a remote machine, since unix socket is a file in local filesystem. With port specified, but port can not be used with a unix-domain-sockets.  Try specifying IP address of a remote server  instead of the (/var/run/postgresql) (unix-domain socket)

Comment: But how do I specify the address if I run on the same server where the db is stored? and what if there are several databases on a localhost?

Comment: i tried jdbc: postgresql: localhost: 5432/var/run/postgresql, it's doesn't work

Comment: Ok, app and postgres located on the same server. Then you may use /var/run/postgres to connect. But you should not specify `port` when you using a unix socket.  Please try filling only socket path `/var/run/postgresql`, with empty `host` and `port`.

Comment: Even if I specify the address like this: `<property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql:/var/run/postgresql</property>`  I get this answer  ` [org.postgresql.Driver] (default task-1) Connection error: : org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "/var/run/postgresql:5432" does not exist`

Comment: OK, I'm trying to send a test connection through the admin console and I can't do it, although wildfly sees the database

Comment: Look: you have port specified here -> /var/run/postgresql:**5432** <-, though you're connecting to a unix socket. That's wrong, isn't it? Can you please try to find, why that happens?

Comment: Please take a look at the [docs for the Postgres driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html).